# Is partitioning an SSD and HDD worth it?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, readyboost

Purchased a 250GB SSD to boost up my lower-end PC build to go along with my 1TB HDD and considering my clogged up Windows 7 from upgrades and bad decicions I've been planning on reformating everything on my HDD and install Windows 10 into my new SSD along with some of my frequently used games.

After some talking with lecturers and other computer enthusiast, I've come under the impression that it would important to partition your drives: keep OS and files separate, extra partition for paging/swapping, restoration partitions, a partition for keeping logs etc. Talking about this topic with people gives me different results though, from people saying it would be practically pointless to people being quite adamant on their neccessity.

Honestly, I'm confused. Who should I trust? Is partitioning an SSD worth it or not?

Extra Question: Since my RAM is kinda low for some tasks (4GB), I've heard about stories that using Win10 ReadyBoost on an USB drive and using that as a page file boosts things up a bit, is it true?

Comment: I think most of the benefits of single disk partitioning can be summed up in these two articles. http://www.pcworld.com/article/185941/how_and_why_to_partition_your_hard_drive.html and http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-reasons-why-you-should-use-more-one-partition-your-pc so read through it and if any of those benefits sound appealing to you or if you truly fear losing your partition's index file (1st article) then feel free to partition. Do note that the speed increase (2nd article) applies specifically to mechanical disks and not SSDs.

Comment: ReadyBoost was contrived by Microsoft to patch Vista's epidemic-level awfulness on lower-end PCs with 2GB of RAM or less. 4GB is plenty for Windows 7/8/10 32-bit or 64-bit. I used to run Windows 7 on 2GB of RAM and it ran like a champ.

Comment: Your second paragraph sounds like he gave you advice aimed at Linux. It doesn’t apply to Windows.

Comment: I would say not as much aimed at Linux as at server environments. And it applies just as well to windows servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've come under the impression that it would important to partition your
>   drives: keep OS and files separate, extra partition for paging/swapping, 
>   restoration partitions, a partition for keeping logs etc.

This is something which is not needed, but often still is a good idea.

Putting the OS on its own partition does make it easier in some situations where you have to reinstall the OS. Just wipe everything (where everything is everything on the OS partition) and reinstall. If all your data happens to be on a different volume than the OS is on then there is no need to restore that from backups.

So nice, but not absolutely needed.

> extra partition for paging/swapping,

This can be a bit more relevant for classic harddisks.  If you have a second disk (a physical disk, not just a different partition on the same disk) then you can use that disk for the pagefile. With the computer able to access to drives at ones when paging performance might be better.  (That is assuming an equally fast disk).

It can also help when windows is set to dynamically grow the pagefile when needed since there are not other writes to the disk which can cause fragmentation.  But you can archieve similar results by disabling swap after your installation, defragging the drive(s) and then reenabling swap with a large minimal size.

So yes, can be useful  (if you do page a lot and have a second disk).
And no, as in usually not worth it. More memory is often a better solution than a dedicated second drive.

> Honestly, I'm confused. Who should I trust? Is partitioning an SSD worth
>   it or not?

Now we get to an SSD. SSDs do not have physical heads to move around. They do not need for a rotating platter to spin to the right placeunder a head. You usually do not gain any performance by partitioning an SSD.

You do gain the cleanliness of different filesystems.

> Extra Question: Since my RAM is kinda low for some tasks (4GB), I've heard
>   about stories that using Win10 ReadyBoost on an USB drive and using that as
>   a page file boosts things up a bit, is it true?

Uhm, win10. Your post is tagged windows 7, not windows 10.

Windows 10 already installs on multiple partition by default (EFI system partition, that ms partition, a restore partition). Not any which are mounted and visible to the user, but they are already used.

As to ready boost: It uses flash media to boost random block reads. If does not boost performance from an SSD. It can help with a classic HDD. Do not use it if you have an SSD or if you have a very slow pendrive.

Answer (score 2):

> Honestly, I'm confused. Who should I trust? Is partitioning an SSD worth it or not?

If you have a reason to partition it, then partition it. But otherwise, it's just a pain because you frequently find the free space is in the wrong partition. Most people don't bother.

> Extra Question: Since my RAM is kinda low for some tasks (4GB), I've heard about stories that using Win10 ReadyBoost on an USB drive and using that as a page file boosts things up a bit, is it true?

No. ReadyBoost was an ugly solution to a problem people don't have any more and USB drives tend to have poor latency. Put the page file on your SSD.